# how to fix the last div container on the bottom of the sidebar

Tags: html, css

i build a basic sidebar, with an navigation list inside. What i'm trying is to get the last div container `.sidebar-footer` on the bottom of the sidebar. When i gave the class a position absolute, it's overlaying over the list item, what should i do to get it like in our design pic?
[image: demo pic]

```
<div class="pulse-menu">
    <div class="menu-bg clearfix">
        <div class="sidebar-profile">
            <img src="img/users/avatar.jpg" class="sidebar-img" alt="Candice Swanepoel" title="Candice Swanepoel" />
            <h5>Candice Swanepoel</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kunden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Finanzen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitarbeiter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Einstellung</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sidebar-footer">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cloud-upload circle-icon">        </i></a></li>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.pulse-menu {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 19.286em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu-bg {
  width: 270px;
  height: 230px;
  background: url(../img/media/menu_bg.svg) ;
  background-size: 270px 221px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sidebar-profile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 0.6em;
}

.sidebar-profile img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  width:60px;
}

.sidebar-profile h5 {
  padding-top: 0.50em;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  font-size: 1.02em;
}

.pulse-menu>nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pulse-menu>nav>ul>li>a {
  color:#333;
  display:block;
  font-size:1.02em;
  height:40px;
  line-height:0px;
  padding-bottom:1.5em;
  padding-left:2em;
  padding-right:2em;
  padding-top:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
}
```

here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL18d7bx/1/) with my code

Comment: Absolute positioning, or flexbox.

Comment: user  :last-child Selector

Comment: Flexbox. Absolute positioning almost always have side effects (like what if the bar is too short for all the buttons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your footer class this styles

```
.sidebar-footer{
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
list-style-type: none;
padding-bottom:5.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:last-child` selector in your CSS.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kunden</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Finanzen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mitarbeiter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Einstellung</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cloud-upload circle-icon">        </i></a></li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav ul li:last-child {
   //your styling
  }
```

Comment: i change the html, i think its better to have them in a seperate div container, outside the list item. but when i gave them a position:absoulte, isn't it working for me

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
<style>
.pulse-menu {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 19.286em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu-bg {
  width: 270px;
  height: 230px;
  background: url(../img/media/menu_bg.svg) ;
  background-size: 270px 221px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sidebar-profile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 0.6em;
}

.sidebar-profile img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  width:60px;
}

.sidebar-profile h5 {
  padding-top: 0.50em;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  font-size: 1.02em;
}

.pulse-menu>nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pulse-menu>nav>ul>li>a {
  color:#333;
  display:block;
  font-size:1.02em;
  height:40px;
  line-height:0px;
  padding-bottom:1.5em;
  padding-left:2em;
  padding-right:2em;
  padding-top:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
}
.specialelement  {
    padding-top: 500px;
    display:block;
    padding-left:6em;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #333;

}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pulse-menu">
    <div class="menu-bg clearfix">
        <div class="sidebar-profile">
            <img src="img/users/avatar.jpg" class="sidebar-img" alt="Candice Swanepoel" title="Candice Swanepoel" />
            <h5>Candice Swanepoel</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kunden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Finanzen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitarbeiter</a></li>
            <li class="specialelement">  

            <li><a href="#">Einstellung</a></li>
            </li>
            <div class="sidebar-footer">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cloud-upload circle-icon">        </i></a></li>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>
```

[Result](http://scratchpad.io/acrid-organization-6241)